# Floating-point error when checking for coplanar 3D points

Tags: c++, 3d, floating-point, floating-point-precision

I am looking for an algorithm to check if a point is coplanar with a given 3D plane, defined out of three vertices, while minimizing floating point errors.

I would like to minimize the amount of multiplications and division to mitigate floating point errors.

My implementation uses `float`s, I cannot go `double`.

I cannot use an external library.

---

My current method suffers from these errors:

I have code defining a plane using the general form of the plane equation:

```
ax + by + cz + d = 0
```

I compute these coefficients using three 3D vertices `v0`, `v1` and `v2` as follow:

```
// Pseudo-code to define a plane (with class Vector3 defining a vector in 3D)
Vector3 A = v1 - v0;
Vector3 B = v2 - v0;
Vector3 N = cross_product(A,B); // Normal vector
N.Normalize();                  // Unit normal vector storing coefs. a, b, c
float d = dot_product(N,v0);
```

To check if another vertex `p` is coplanar, I plug the point into the plane equation and check if the result is `0`:

```
// Pseudo-code for coplanar test:
bool is_coplanar()
{
    float res = N.x()*p.x() + N.y()*p.y() + N.z()*p.z() - d;
    return true if res is "almost" null; // "almost" is: abs(res)<EPSILON
}
```

---

My code fails in this case:

```
v0 = [-8.50001907, 0, 323]
v1 = [8.49998093, 0, 323]
v2 = [-8.50001907, 1.49999976, 322.598083]
```

Then the plane coefficients are:

```
N = [-0, 0.258814692, 0.965926945]
d = 311.994415
```

And when I plug the point `v2`, I find a result "far" from `0` (although `v2` was used to define the plane):

```
res = -3.05175781e-05
```

My `EPSILON` is currently `1e-5`.

Tested on compiler qcc 4.4.2 (QNX Momentics, similar to gcc). With no optimization `-O0`.

Comment: In your example, abs(res) > EPSILON, so it should return false, correct?

Comment: Yes, code fails to find `v2` is coplanar in this case, although `v2` was used to define the plane.

Comment: Oh okay, I see what your question is now, let me take another look at the code.

Comment: How did you pick the value for `EPSILON`? Do you have a reason for believing the value of `res`, if calculated with exact mathematics (no rounding errors), would not already be farther from zero than `EPSILON` due to errors in calculating `N` and `d`? In other words, if the errors that occurred in calculating `N` and `d` have moved the plane described by them far enough, then it is possible that `v2` is not close enough to the plane that even an exact calculation of `res` would be less than `EPSILON`.

Comment: More than that, perhaps it is possible that it is impossible for any `N` and `d` to be sufficiently close to the proper plane because the necessary values to make such an `N` and a `d` are not representable in the floating-point format. (Note that the ULP of `d` is around 1.5e-5, so it can only be adjusted by steps of that amount, already larger than `EPSILON`.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil, thanks for your input. My question is to find another method that do not rely on these computations so I don't have to answer your tricky questions :)

Comment: Well, you are in luck. If *N* and *d* are calculated with exact mathematics and then rounded to the nearest `float` values and then `res` is calculated with exact mathematics from those values and `v2`, then it is less than 1e-5, approximately 0.0000051611115. Unfortunately, the values you calculated for `N` and `d` are already ruined. When `res` is calculated exactly from those values, it is exactly −0.000011984341398374454001896083354949951171875, which exceeds 1e-5. Therefore, no minimization of errors in calculating `res` will produce a result with magnitude less than 1e-5.

Comment: Therefore, you must fix the calculations of `N` and `d` or accept a higher value for `EPSILON`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such geometric predicates suffer in a lot of ways from floating point errors. The only industrial strength solution is to use [adaptable arithmetic filtering](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/papers/robustr.pdf) (provided that a robust implementation of the `coplanar` test is not covering you).

Luckily such [implementations](http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/graphics/asymptote/predicates.cc) (that would take quite some time to write) are already available. In the previous link the **orient3d** predicate does what you need: **Given 3 plane forming points, decide whether a 4th one lies above,below or on the plane**

If such an implementation is an overkill, check the simple one. It offers 4 in total:

> orient3dfast()   Approximate 3D orientation test.  Nonrobust.
>    orient3dexact()  Exact 3D orientation test.  Robust.
>    orient3dslow()   Another exact 3D orientation test.  Robust.
>    orient3d()       Adaptive exact 3D orientation test.  Robust.

**Disclaimer**: The code listing is provided as a tutorial of the mathematical concepts and programming techniques needed to reach a robust solution. I'm neither suggesting nor implying copy-pasting anything.

Comment: Ten years ago exactly this paper made me a better coder!